# Related to Printing HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I am trying to fill a hidden attribute with php variable .

```
echo"<form method=\"get\" action=\"page2.php\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\"var_value\">";
echo"<span class=\"Icon Icon--delete Icon--large\"> </span>";
echo "<input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Delete\" style=\" background: transparent; border: 0;      font-family: Tahoma;   border-radius: 4px; width: 50px; height:30px;\">";
echo"</form>";
```

In the code above in place of `var_value` I want a php variable like `$task["id"]`, I have tried to put it as

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\" "; . $task["id"]; echo "\">";
```

.... but it is not working, what should I do ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know inline styling is not good.

Comment: This is very ugly and sooner or later it will be even uglier if you keep developing this way. seperate presentation from logic, DO NOT ECHO OUT HTML.

Comment: @Ali Thanks for your guidance.But how in a case where I have to display a list of items that I receive as a json response, I can avoid echo ? Please give some links so that I can learn a better way . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try string concatenation:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\"" . $task["id"] ."\">";
```

Or multiple echoes:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\""; echo $task["id"]; echo "\">";
```

What about single qoutes?:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="' . $task['id'] . '">';
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. My error was due to one space after value\, right ? Thanks again.

Comment: no, not due to the "space after value\" its because you are printing the html stuffs not the `$task["id"]`

Answer (score 3):

just do this as you have already used echo...

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\" ". $task["id"]. "\">";
```

if trying to print a value like **if** condition use

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\" ". (($task["id"] != "")?'$task["id"]':"empty id"). "\">";
```

try using **PHP IN HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="varname" value=" <? echo $task["id"];?> " \>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already inside the echo statement's echo string all you need to do is concatenate the string as:

```
 echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varname\" value=\"" . $task["id"] . "\">";
```

Alternatively you could just output the plain html code as is and only open php tags for the outputting of the variables needed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="<?php echo $task["id"];?>">
```

which makes the code look cleaner and allows the IDE you are using to take up the `html` markup as html and it is easier to spot mistakes through all that quote escaping and mixed `html`/`php` code

Answer (score 1):

Use String concatenation! like this:

```
<?php

    echo '<form method="get" action="page2.php">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="' . $task["id"] . '">';
        echo '<span class="Icon Icon--delete Icon--large"></span>';
        echo '<input type="Submit" value="Delete" style=" background: transparent; border: 0;      font-family: Tahoma;   border-radius: 4px; width: 50px; height:30px;">';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make it more cleaner**

Close the `php tag` Before the form

```
?>

<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="var_value">
<span class="Icon Icon--delete Icon--large"> </span>
<input type="Submit" value="Delete" style=" background: transparent; border: 0;      font-family: Tahoma;   border-radius: 4px; width: 50px; height:30px;">
</form>


<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="<?php echo $task["id"]?> ">
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [printf](http://php.net/manual/it/function.printf.php) ?

```
<?php $myvar = 'hi'; ?>

<form method="get" action="page2.php">
  <?php printf('<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="%s" />', htmlspecialchars((string)$myvar)); ?>

  <span class="Icon Icon--delete Icon--large"> </span>
  <input type="Submit" value="Delete" style=" background: transparent; border: 0;      font-family: Tahoma;   border-radius: 4px; width: 50px; height:30px;">
</form>
```

**Result**

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="hi &amp; I use quote &quot; too" />
  <span class="Icon Icon--delete Icon--large"> </span>
  <input type="Submit" value="Delete" style=" background: transparent; border: 0;      font-family: Tahoma;   border-radius: 4px; width: 50px; height:30px;">
</form>
```

By using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/it/function.htmlspecialchars.php) you also ensure `HTML` will be valid whatever you write.
Check [eval'd code](https://eval.in/210079) and tweak with it